# CreateFileMapping - Shared Memory Applications

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management

this is my first question here. I hope dont make any mistake, be good with me...

I am very confused with shared files..
I have two applications and I want to exchange data between them. 
I tried with CreatefileMapping functions but now I need an event that warn me when the shared file have new data from the other application (is it possible?)

I dont know if it will possible with a filesystemwatcher because i dont have a file path...

Do you recommend working with Messaging instead??

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't be confused: these are file mappings (important word is 'mapping'), not files. These are memory section visible to possibly 2+ processes. You normally make them named so that your two apps could find them. The same way you can use named event to additionally synchronize access to this shared resource.

Answer (score 0):

You can synchronize your to applicattion with help of named objects called evnts
when other application have new data that time it should set one event and other 
application should wait for that event.

Once it got event then it should reload the database.